# gotoAndPlay issue

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, switch-statement, goto

Can anybody assist me with AS3 gotoAndPlay(). I have researched the usage of this function in AS3 but for some reason my code does not work.

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
function disInfo(event:MouseEvent):void
{
switch (event.currentTarget.name)
{
    case "one_mc" :
    Object(this).top_mc.one_mc.gotoAndPlay(2);
        break;
    case "two_mc" :
        gotoAndPlay(2);
        break;
}
};
Object(this).top_mc.two_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, disInfo);
```

Is it something to do with the way I have used it in conjunction with switch statement. Thanks in advance.

Comment: your currentTarget is always going to be  two_mc because that's what you've attached the listener to.

Answer (score 0):

I think, your code some spaghetti.

your code is strange.. not addEventListener `top.one_mc`.

refer a following code.

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;

function disInfo(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var mc:MovieClip = event.currentTarget as MovieClip;

    mc.gotoAndPlay(2);
};

top.one_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, disInfo);
top.two_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, disInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you tell us more about what you are trying to do? We need to know what your elements are called, and what you want to do before we can give you a clear answer.

Use the following code to determine if your switch is working. **Let us know what is traced**:

```
 import flash.display.MovieClip; 
    function disInfo(event:MouseEvent):void {  
    trace(event.currentTarget.name); 
    switch (event.currentTarget.name) {
        case "one_mc" :
        Object(this).top_mc.one_mc.gotoAndPlay(2);
            break;
        case "two_mc" :
            gotoAndPlay(2);
            break; } 
}; 
    Object(this).top_mc.two_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, disInfo);
```

Comment: I am trying to call gotoAndPlay() on two individual timelines through one function. The paths are different for each timelines. I have never used gotoAndPlay in AS3. It used to be so easy in AS2.

Comment: Have you tried tracing the value of "event.currentTarget.name" before the switch to make sure that it contains the correct value?

Comment: From your code I assume that you have a movie clip with the instance name "top", which in turn contains a child element with the instance name "one_mc". What exactly are you trying to do with "Object(this)"?Is "top" sitting on the main timeline? If so then you do not need to add "Object(this)" in front of it.

Comment: phunder :doesn't work have tried, the problem lies with the gotoAndPlay I believe, just don't know enough about it.

Comment: if you want to follow this approach, I recommend that you insert some trace-statements to figure out if the listener gets called:(trace("function disInfo(event:MouseEvent):void"), how many frames are in the movie clips that you are trying to access.

Comment: @ bjornson Have done the trace already, it works and the currentTarget.Name gets traced correctly. there are 10 frame, does it make a difference?